# How to Navigate Automatically to next screen after getting location

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I am new to react native. I have created Screen to access location. I copy this code from expo website. now its working but screen only location access screen is showing I am not able to move to my app means to the next welcome screen.

here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Hello, I could not understand your question. Are you getting the location but you can not go to the welcome screen, where is your welcome screen? Please give me more details, more code and more context. Waiting for your feedback. Thx :).

Comment: Yes actually I created an app then now I have added location screen now whenever I run that app location screen is showing. I want to save user location in background, I do not want to Show location screen, I want that logic to run in background

Comment: Now I understood better. So, if you want to work with background tasks in Expo please use the [BackgroundFecth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) lib or the [TaskManager](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/) lib. Remember that before all you have to ask for the location permission, after that, you can begin to get the user location in the background. Waiting for your feedback, Thx :).

Comment: where should I use it in above code

Comment: Actually I never worked with background tasks in react-native but as I'm seeing your code I thinkk you should put ```  let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);``` as a background task, you got it? He will keep getting user location.

Comment: Ok Baghto sangto tula

Comment: Please, if my comment really helped you, thumbs up my comment :). I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: Yes, Thank You. If I have any query further I will ping you here, thanks BTW

Comment: Hey Gabriel, I have another silly problem just check it => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734714/react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227380/discussion-between-gabriel-menezes-da-silva-and-sohil-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use React Navigation to navigate between screens.

Here's a [link to the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started). Follow instructions in the documentation and you should be able to add navigation to your app very quickly.